# How does artifactory interact with multiple web containers

Tags: artifactory

I am new to Artifactory and I have Artifactory installed in my local machine and is deployed on the standard Tomcat web container and a Weblogic web container.  I want to know how Artfactory stores the artifacts.  Would it be in the web container or would it be stored on my local machine?

Also is it possible to connect the storage meaning that if I deployed an artifact on my local machine with the Weblogic server is it possible to configure Artifactory such that if I use the Tomcat container I can still access the artifact deployed when I was using the Weblogic server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artifactory stores the actual binaries on the disk (by recommended default) and metadata about the binaries in a JDBC compliant database (Derby by default, but you can use other supported http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Changing+the+Default+Storage)

Usually, you need only one Artifactory instance. Even though technically you could configure multiple instances of Artifactory to use the same directory for artifacts and the same connection to the metadata database, this setup will probably corrupt both the artifacts storage and the metadata database by executing concurrent writes.

**DO NOT DO IT.**

Comment: So does that mean I cannot have one instance of artifactory be on two different web containers?

Comment: @BrandonFung Not when they are both running. Can you please elaborate why you want to do such a thing?

Comment: Well I don't want to run both of them at the same time, I just want to test which web container would be the most ideal for what we want to do.

Comment: Then go for it - configure them both to the same $ARTIFACTORY_HOME and you're done. Just don't, I repeat, don't run them on the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Artifactory stores data into a JDBC compliant database, I guess it's Derby by default but you can use MySql, etc. http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF20/Running+Artifactory+on+MySQL

Usually, you need only one Artifactory instance. Even though <strike>it should works on multiple containers if you share the data through the same database</strike>, **I would advice you to use a unique instance**

Comment: thanks, but how do I check if there are sharing databases and not just using two copies of the database?

Comment: Check your database settings http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF20/Running+Artifactory+on+MySQL

Comment: Thanks again, but i am still stuck, so i know that both of the instances use derby but is it possible to find the path in which artifactory stores the binaries?